# Sending intent to an activity that killed itself

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

Suppose I start with Activity A which invokes Activity B. So the Task looks like A->B with B at the top. 
B sends an intent to start Activity C and after sending the intent to C, B invokes finish() on itself. So the stack would look like A->C.

Now when I was sending an intent to Activity B with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, I noticed its onCreate() wasn't called. But when I added the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP along with the aforementioned one, it worked.

2 questions:

1. Why didn't it work with just FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ?
2. What changed with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ?

I have gone through the official documentation of both the flags but cannot co-relate the explanation with the above scenario.

Comment: You need to add the code, which shows launching mechanism.

Comment: Becuase it is unclear exactly **how** you lauch activities. I mean what the flags you use, and what you mean under on "send intent to C/A/B"

Comment: A is the root activity, and all remaining activities are started by sending explicit intents to them in the order mentioned above. Apologies that the code is too huge and hence I only want to understand the concepts involved here.

Comment: So, it's ok. You use explicit intents to launch activities. Did you use some launchModes in declaration of activities in your manifest?

Comment: Yes. The launch mode is "singleTop" for all